# Is it okay to modify a bunch of CW posts to make them more uniform?

Tags: support, edits, community-wiki, etiquette

I was looking at the question [What are those little Xcode tips & tricks you wish you knew 2 years ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/what-are-those-little-xcode-tips-tricks-you-wish-you-knew-about-2-years-ago), the problem is that it's hard to read all the answers to this post. Mainly because they are all formatted differently. Some have included just the keyboard shortcut keys, while others have included one or more paragraphs describing a keyboard shortcut.

I think users would benefit if there was a standard to all these answers (e.g. keyboard keys formatted with the `<kbd>`, and any necessary explanations would be underneath that).

My question is if it's alright for me to modify a bunch of these answers so that they are more uniform. I would also ensure that I don't remove any important information the original answerer has posted.

I have done this for the top 3 highest rated answers, I'm wondering if it's okay to do it to the rest.

If you want to take a look at what kind of editing I'm talking about, just view the revisions of these top 3 answers.

Comment: Those look great.  As long as you're just changing format and leaving content alone, I say go for it.

Comment: Looks good, but FYI the symbols in the 1st and 3rd answers aren't showing up for me. (XP + FF 3.6.3)

Comment: @Jon: Yeah I'm using Chrome on both XP and OS X. There's only one that doesn't show up on XP for me (Escape). However, since this is a Mac related question, I'm guessing that most users will probably view it on a Mac where it is more likely to be viewable and look much nicer. That's also the reason I'm adding the name of the key in addition to the symbol.

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point. Carry on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knock yourself out. That's what CW is for...

However, please pay close attention to how your edits are received by others: if the posted start to collect comments or rollbacks, you'd do well to find out why before continuing.